# ValueError Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') Scitkit Learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, valueerror

I have read through so many posts regarding this and cannot find my answer.

```
import pandas as pd
```

After import pandas, I read a csv file using pandas.read_csv. The csv file has 32 columns and ~280,000 rows.

```
data = pd.read_csv(path)
# Add unique index column to data
data = data.reset_index()
```

I then use the pandas.dropna function to ensure my data doesn't have any nan values.

```
dropped_values = data.dropna(inplace=True)
print(dropped_value.dtypes)
# returns all float64 types
```

**Also checked these from popular upvoted answer**

```
np.any(np.isnan(dropped_values))
# prints false
np.all(np.isfinite(dropped_values))
# prints true
```

**and yet I still receive**

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

...

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-75-f81bb23d00b2> in <module>
     76 
     77 
     ---> 78 for train_index, test_index in strat_split.split(dropped_values, 
     dropped_values["time_attribute"]):
```

from the line with the for loop

```
strat_split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

dropped_values["time_attribute"] = pd.cut(dropped_values["Time"], 
                                       bins=[0., 35000, 70000, 105000, 140000, 175000., np.inf],
                                       labels=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])


for train_index, test_index in strat_split.split(dropped_values, dropped_values["time_attribute"]):
    strat_train_set = dropped_values.loc[train_index]
    strat_test_set = dropped_values.loc[test_index]
```

I have also tried imputing the data using SimpleImputer before I try to call the StartifySplit.
Additionally, I have tried many other variations of dropna found in other posts' comments and nothing seems to work.

This doesn't make sense because I have viewed the data, printed the data types, check whether they are nan or finite and everything is giving the correct answer.

**Anybody have any other suggestions to try?**

Please note I changed the variable names in my post to make it more generic. If I accidentally missed a letter/character it was probably just a mistake while creating the post.

Comment: I haven't tried inplace=True with assigning the results to a new DataFrame. Can you try without inplace=True? inplace=True is used to update the same DataFrame on which an operation is being carried out. Since you are assigning it to a new variable, I don't see the need for it. Not sure, if it will fix it but something worth trying. Lastly, is it possible for you to share a reproducible sample?

Comment: Yes, I actually originally tried without inplace=True.  I added it in because I saw some other posts saying that was something they found success with. 

For the sample, what exactly would you want to see? Something like data.head() to print out the first few rows? or the results of isnan and isfinite calls?

Comment: I see. Well, I need something that I can try and reproduce on my laptop. More info can be found here - [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)